# JS function that counts from multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, html, input, output

I have made a simple calculator that takes the information entered by the user in , then performs an action with two const and gives the result in a selected .

In total, i have 5 inputs and 5 outputs. To each input and output i have 2 const.

Code looks like that:

```js
const suprqMean = 3.93;
const usabilityMean = 4.06;

const suprqSD = 0.29;
const usabilitySD = 0.29; 

{
  const input = document.querySelector("#formGroupExampleInput");
  const log = document.getElementById("#suprq");

  input.addEventListener("change", updateValue);

  function updateValue(e) {
    suprq.textContent = (e.target.value - suprqMean) / suprqSD;
  }
}

{
  const input = document.querySelector("#formGroupExampleInput1");
  const log = document.getElementById("#usability");

  input.addEventListener("change", updateValue);

  function updateValue(e) {
    usability.textContent = (e.target.value - usabilityMean) / usabilitySD;
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="leftForm container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">SUPR-Q raw</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="SUPR-Q raw">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Usability raw</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput1" placeholder="Usability raw">
  </div>
</form>

<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col">Z-Score</th>
      <th scope="col">Result</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>SUPR-Q:</td>
      <td id="suprq"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Usability:</td>
      <td id="usability"></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And it works , but the JS code looks awful. Is there any way to optimise the JS code? I want the result to be entered in real time as it works now.

Comment: so use input event instead of change.

Comment: It shouldn't work because you're passing strings into functions when you mean to be passing numbers:

`e.target.value` is a string and will always be string regardless of the input type. All inputs pass strings

use the shorthand `+` in front, like `+e.target.value` which will automatically convert the string into a number for your math.

Comment: but as we all know, under the hood the subtraction will do the conversion, hence why it works.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and tell us if it's what you searching for. Maybe someone have a more condensed version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's is a 'condensed' version

```js
const values = {
  suprqMean: 3.93,
  usabilityMean: 4.06,
  suprqSD: .29,
  usabilitySD: .29
};
["suprq", "usability"].map((slug => {
  document.querySelector(`#${slug}Input`).addEventListener("change", (clicked => {
    document.getElementById(`${slug}`).textContent = (clicked.target.value - values[`${slug}Mean`]) / values[`${slug}SD`]
  }))
}));
```

```html
<form class="leftForm container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">SUPR-Q raw</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="suprqInput" placeholder="SUPR-Q raw">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Usability raw</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="usabilityInput" placeholder="Usability raw">
  </div>
</form>

<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col">Z-Score</th>
      <th scope="col">Result</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>SUPR-Q:</td>
      <td id="suprq"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Usability:</td>
      <td id="usability"></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The code works great!  Thanks for that :)

Comment: YOu can also reduce the `v` by using `v[${t}Mean] = xx;` :) ANd you can use same logic for 'Mean' an 'SD' so you get 2 arrays that you combine and loop on. Tadaam

Comment: I generally recommend avoiding single-letter variable names. They don't mean as much as real words and are harder to find with Find (ctrl+f) or `grep` and the like.

Comment: Not supposed to be use "AS IS" snippet here to explain the logic. But you're right. Answer edited

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two functions into one by checking `e.target.id` inside, and select both input values at once to loop through and add the event listener:

```js
const suprqMean = 3.93;
const usabilityMean = 4.06;
const suprqSD = 0.29;
const usabilitySD = 0.29;

document.querySelectorAll("[id^=formGroupExampleInput").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("change", updateValue);
});

function updateValue(e) {
  inpVer = e.target.id === "formGroupExampleInput" ? true : false;
  outEl = inpVer ? suprq : usability;
  outVal = inpVer ? (e.target.value - suprqMean) / suprqSD : (e.target.value - usabilityMean) / usabilitySD;
  outEl.textContent = outVal;
}
```

```html
<form class="leftForm container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">SUPR-Q raw</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="SUPR-Q raw">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Usability raw</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput1" placeholder="Usability raw">
  </div>
</form>

<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col">Z-Score</th>
      <th scope="col">Result</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>SUPR-Q:</td>
      <td id="suprq"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Usability:</td>
      <td id="usability"></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are somewhat repeating yourself in that JS code.

The usual remedy for this would be to refactor the repeated code into a reusable function:

```
const suprqMean = 3.93;
const usabilityMean = 4.06;

const suprqSD = 0.29;
const usabilitySD = 0.29;


function listenForChanges (inputId, logId, output, mean, SD) {
  const input = document.querySelector(inputId);
  const log = document.querySelector(logId);

  input.addEventListener("change", updateValue);

  function updateValue(e) {
    output.textContent = (e.target.value - mean) / SD;
  }
}

listenForChanges("#formGroupExampleInput", "#suprq", suprq, suprqMean, suprqSD)
listenForChanges("#formGroupExampleInput1", "#usability", usability, usabilityMean, usabilitySD)
```

Something else feels weird though. In your original snippet (and in mine too) there are references to two variables that are never declared: `suprq` and `usability`.

But apart from that, do you like this use of a function as a first step to make the code a little bit less "awful"?

If you have many of these, the next step could be to make a data structure for all the input pairs and call this function on each pair with a loop:

```
const all = [{
  inputId: "#formGroupExampleInput",
  logId: "#suprq",
  output: suprq,
  mean: 3.93,
  SD: 0.29
}, {
  inputId: "#formGroupExampleInput1",
  logId: "#usability",
  output: usability,
  mean: 4.06,
  SD: 0.29
}]

all.forEach(listenForChanges)

function listenForChanges ({inputId, logId, output, mean, SD}) {
  const input = document.querySelector(inputId);
  const log = document.querySelector(logId);

  input.addEventListener("change", updateValue);

  function updateValue(e) {
    output.textContent = (e.target.value - mean) / SD;
  }
}
```

Notice that I changed the function a bit here, having it accept a single object parameter instead of a series of parameters. This is just to make it easier to glue everything together with `forEach`.

Comment: It took me a while, but I understood what was going on here :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Others have shown ways to use a configuration array to generate your handlers.

You could also generate the HTML from the same configuration, which means that adding a new type is just the matter of one more configuration entry:

```js
const config = [
  {title: 'SUPR-Q', mean: 3.93, sd: 0.29, input: 'formGroupExampleInput', log: 'suprq'},
  {title: 'Usability', mean: 4.06, sd: 0.29, input: 'formGroupExampleInput1', log: 'usability'}
]

document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = `
<form class="leftForm container">
  ${config .map (({title, input}) => `  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="${input}">${title} raw</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="${input}" placeholder="${title} raw">
  </div>`) .join ('\n'  )}
</form>

<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
  <thead><tr><th scope="col">Z-Score</th><th scope="col">Result</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>${config .map (({title, output}) => 
      `<tr><td>${title}</td><td id="${output}"></td></tr>`).join('\n    ')
  }</tbody>
</table>`

config .forEach (({title, mean, sd, input, log}) => {
  const inputElt = document.getElementById(input);
  const logElt = document.getElementById(log);

  inputElt.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    logElt.textContent = (e.target.value - mean) / sd;
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

I also switched to a consistent `getElementById`.  We could just as easily use `querySelector` here, but mixing them feels odd when we're always getting ids.